# What do you call the motor that fuels the movement of a robotic arm?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the motor that fuels the movement of a robotic arm? Is there a word that applies to all robots and not just some of them. I can't remember the word that was used. I am also talking about all movements or anything that requires energy including maintaining the robotic arm's position.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is normally called a "servo", short for "servomechanism":

> **[servomechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servomechanism)** (n): In control engineering a servomechanism, sometimes shortened to servo, is an automatic device that uses error-sensing negative feedback to correct the action of a mechanism.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servomechanism) It usually includes a built-in encoder or other position feedback mechanism to ensure the output is achieving the desired effect.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuator)

Note:  We don't say a servo "fuels" the movement of a robot arm.  The verb "fuel" (or "power") is used to describe the power source for engines which require some kind of external *fuel*.  Instead we would say the servo "drives" the movement of a robot arm.

Servos can be *fueled/powered* by a variety of sources. Electric is probably most common, but other options are such things as *hydraulic* or *steam* power.

(Edit) moooeeeep also suggests "actuator", which seems equally valid:

> [**actuator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuator) (n): An actuator is a component of a machine that is responsible for moving and controlling a mechanism or system, for example by opening a valve. In simple terms, it is a "mover".

If you're asking for the purpose of writing science fiction, then either is fine.  I've seen both used.  "Actuator" seems to be more commonly used when talking about a mechanism's design:

> "Built into the inside of the suit was a weblike network of miniature **actuators** that made contact with my skin every few centimeters" - *Ready Player One*, Ernest Cline

and "servo" seems to be used when talking about a mechanism's movement:

> "The robot's **servos** kicked in immediately, buzzing erratically ... attempting to lock onto the source of the noise"  - *Dome City Blues*, Jeff Edwards

Comment: More generally one could also say [_actuator_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuator).

Answer (score 5):

In many robots, the motor is a "[stepper motor](https://circuitglobe.com/stepper-motor.html)".  A stepper motor is designed to move a specific number of steps, based on an electrical input.

Answer (score 3):

What about an **actuator**?

> : one that actuates
>
> specifically : a mechanical device for moving or controlling something

Answer (score 1):

**Servos** and **Steppers** are specific types of motors that are generally found on robotic arm joints, but in robotics a moving joint is called an **[axis](https://www.asme.org/topics-resources/content/many-axes-does-robot-need)**.

A typical industrial robot might have six axes, each with its own motor.